# Can't seem to escape character from PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

In my PHP - Codeigniter function(), I gave the following command:

```
function get_cust($search='David')
{
$query = 'select pp.first_name from Cust pp where'; 
$query .= ' pp.first_name LIKE "%'.$search.'%")';
print_r(mysql_real_escape_string($query));
}
```

But while i executed the output in browser:

```
select pp.first_name from Cust pp where pp.first_name LIKE 'Úvid%'
```

Is it anyway so i can get it like:

```
select pp.first_name from Cust pp where pp.first_name LIKE '%David%'
```

I have tried using `addslashes()`, `mysql_real_escape_string()` as well.

Comment: Move away from mysql_* extension. It is removed completely in PHP7
Also, do `mysql_real_escape_string` on `$search` ; not the whole query

Comment: Use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and let the library handle it all for you.

Comment: @Phylogenesis, Can you help me with an example?

Comment: Guys Rather than giving a minus vote, why dont you guys edit my question?

Answer (score -1):

1. Move away from mysql_* extensions. They are remove completely from PHP 7. Switch to either [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) extension or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). [Better use prepared statements, to avoid SQL injection issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).
2. You should do escaping on the parameter, not the whole query.
3. [You should use single quotes around the parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5741264/2469308), even with mysqli_real_escape_string, to prevent SQL injection.
4. [Set your character set to UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string/12118602#12118602).

Find below the changed function, utilizing [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php):

```
function get_cust($search='David')
{
    $query = "select pp.first_name from Cust pp where"; 
    $query .= " pp.first_name LIKE '%".mysqli_real_escape_string($search)."%')";
    print_r($query);
}
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but I feel that just answering the question as-is without actually using `mysqli` or `PDO` and concatenation is a *bad idea*.

Comment: @Phylogenesis well I have already mentioned OP to move to mysqli or PDO with proper references.

Comment: But 99% of people asking this question in Google/Bing are going to look at the code provided and just copy that without reading all the provisos. It just leads to more bad code.

Comment: @Phylogenesis edited to use `mysqli_real_escape_string instead`.

Comment: Guys Rather than giving a minus vote, why dont you guys edit my question?

Comment: But that's still objectively *wrong*. Give an example that actually uses prepared statements.

Comment: @Phylogenesis Well as long as character set is UTF-8 and mysqli_real_escape_string is used properly with single quotes, there is no SQL injection issue. Prepared statement are better; but people still use mysqli based statements (without prepare) as long as few restrictions are well taken care of

Comment: This is an example where not using prepared statements is wrong. It's way too easy to forget to do something properly and you then have a massive SQL injection waiting to be exploited.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya, I am having PHP 5.4 in my local machine. Kindly give me a way in PHP 5.4

Comment: @Keynes it is php 5.4 way only. You will need to switch to using mysqli_* extension. In the code where you are creating Mysql connection, you will need to switch to using mysqli extension there. If you could give details of that area of the code, I could change and give further explanation here